# Копирование файлов в виртуальную машину VMWare. Расположение папки с проектом в VMBitrix7.5-1-CentOS7.9-VMWare

Tags: база-данных, битрикс, файловая-система, виртуальная-машина, vmware

1. Как скопировать файлы в виртуальную машину VMWare? Перечислите все возможные способы и отметьте самый простой вариант.
2. До виртуальной машины я использовал OpenServer. В нем папки с сайтами располагались по пути D:\OpenServer\domains. Где хранится папка с проектами (сайтами на bitrix, созданными мною с помощью 1С Bitrix) на VMBitrix7.5-1-**CentOS7.9**-VMWare (на виртуальной машине, являющейся веб-сервером)? Там OpenServer-а нет. Папки специально располагаются на VMBitrix7.5-1-**CentOS7.9**-VMWare, скачанного с [Виртуальные машины](https://1c-bitrix.ru/download/vmbitrix.php).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Как я уже и отмечал - я использовал OpenServer. В нем базы данных для сайтов я создавал с помощью Openserver -> Дополнительно -> PhpMyAdmin. Как создать базу данных для проекта на VMBitrix7.5-1-CentOS7.9-VMWare на виртуальной машине?

Comment: Пройдите урок по виртуальной машине битрикс https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&CHAPTER_ID=08809

Answer (score 0):

Копировать перетаскиванием (вручную) или через общие папки (тут и программно можно).

VMWare ни на что не влияет. Где папки раполагаются без VMWare, там они и располагаются, если система запущена на VMWare.

Если вы перешли с OpenServer на CentOS, то ищите там веб-сервер и его корневую папку. Или настройки Битрикса посмотрите.

Comment: 1. я имел ввиду как осуществлять копирование также как с WinSCP (подобные программы). Какие есть еще способы? 2. Где хранится папка с проектами на VMBitrix7.5-1-CentOS7.9-VMWare (на виртуальной машине, являющейся веб-сервером)?  Там OpenServer-а нет. Папки специально располагаются на VMBitrix7.5-1-CentOS7.9-VMWare, скачанного с https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/vmbitrix.php.

Comment: Ой. OpenServer и CentOS - это операционные системы (ОС), а веб-сервер - это отдельное от ОС приложение. Таких приложений для веб-серверов очень много, например IIS, Apache и т. п.

Comment: OpenServer - это локальный веб-сервер, а CentOS -операционная система для VMBitrix, в которой также располагаются папки с проектами, как и в OpenServer. В OpenServer (зеленый флажок в трее) они находятся в пункте меню **Папка с проектами**, а в VMBitrix7.5-1-CentOS7.9-VMWare где они находятся? См. скриншот в вопросе. И в локальном сервере, и в виртуальной машине (поставляемой 1с bitrix) могут быть проекты (папки с сайтами).